# Avoiding index & match #N/A value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am indexing `column O` on a match of a value with a combined name within `column L`.

If the combined name is not found within the table I am index/matching, I will be passed back a `#N/A` value. How could I avoid this? I've looked into the `ISNA` function however it only passes back a `True` or `False` value. I could use this to make another formula to set it, but am trying to find a shorter quicker way.

The current index/match being used is:

```
=INDEX(O:O,MATCH(ADIST& " " &APROD,L:L,0))
```

And if I am being passed back a #N/A value I'd like it to say `"No Value"`.

Comment: You could use COUNTIF() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [IFERROR](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) to set an alternative value if the formula you are using returns an error:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(O:O,MATCH(ADIST& " " &APROD,L:L,0)),"No Value")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use IFNA or IFERROR functions, same syntax but IFNA is more accurate on the type of error :

```
=IFNA(expression, value if expression returns an error)
```

so for you :

```
=IFNA(INDEX(O:O,MATCH(ADIST& " " &APROD,L:L,0)),"No Value")
```